# Get a list of all uses of boost:shared_ptr's get method in a source tree

Tags: c++, debugging, boost, shared-ptr

I'm trying to find all cases in a big project where the "get" method of a boost::shared is used -- where something isn't specific.

The problem is that some programmer was sloppy at some point and started to use bare pointers, using foo.get() to take a hold of them. So my goal is to find all places where this get method is used to review and fix the code.

I have pondered modifying the shared_ptr boost header to comment out the method and run make with the "-k" option to spot all such places, but perhaps there's a more elegant way to do that?

Comment: Ctrl+F, ".get()", `<enter>`.

Comment: +1 to comment for simple solution first.

Comment: I suspect that "big project" implies "searching for 'get()' was an avalanche of false positives".

Comment: +1 Drew.Not only is Ctrl+F even an option, find and grep will give you a lot of false +ves. get is the most common method name. The more you try to eliminate false +ve's, the more fancy you will have to get until you say to yourself. "Man! I could've written a c++ parser in this amount of effort"

Comment: Ctrl+F doesn't search in a directory structure, and doesn't do anything smart about the type of the object whose get method is called... Honestly that comment doesn't deserve a +1 (insightful) but a -1 (troll)!

Comment: @JPuydt You want to accept the answer? Were you able to resolve your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like your idea. Sounds like you are concerned about modifying a system header file, which is bad form.

Here is a slightly more elegant idea. copy the header file to /tmp/tmpinclude and then add a CFLAG -I/tmp/tmpinclude and make sure that's the first -I CFlag. Now your hack is contained in your user/sandbox space.